# create database user with postgres on azure

Tags: postgresql

I need to create an additional user on postgres running on azure usually I would do :

```
create user myfineuser with password 'myfinepassword';
grant connect on database myfinedatabase to myfineuser;
```

But when I then try to connect to the db on azure with

```
psql "host=myfinehost.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 \
    dbname=myfinedatabase user=myfineuser password=myfinepassword sslmode=require"
```

I do receive

```
psql: FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The 
Username should be in <username@hostname> format.
```

I did not fine how to specify user@host in the sql statement to create the user

```
myfineuser@myfinehost, 'myfineuser@myfinehost', .... all these permutations do result in a syntax error
```

How can i do this with psql. This article just talks about user but not how to specify user@host https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/postgresql/howto-create-users#how-to-create-database-users-in-azure-database-for-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ist simple :

```
create user myfineuser with password 'myfinepassword';
grant connect on database myfinedatabase to myfineuser;
```

then in psql :

```
psql "host=myfinehost.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 \
dbname=myfinedatabase user=myfineuser@myfinehost password=myfinepassword sslmode=require"
```

note the **myfineuser@myfinehost** in the psql connect string. This is implicit